# Qt5.4 QOpenGLFramebufferObject toImage Returning Blank Image

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qimage

I'm trying to create a `QImage` from the `QOpenGLFramebufferObject` using this example:

https://dangelog.wordpress.com/2013/02/10/using-fbos-instead-of-pbuffers-in-qt-5-2/

I'm just directly copying and pasting the first example and I'm just getting a blank image. I don't know if Qt changed something recently or if it's just me.

here's my project file:

```
QT       += core gui widgets

TARGET = OpenGLTest2
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

I've tried building with `MSVC2012/MSVC2013 OpenGL 32bit/64bit` and `MingW` and it's just blank. Is there something missing in my project file? Do I need to change something in the code? Any help would be great...

Answer (score 0):

Ok after playing with it for a bit, I found out the format version lines were causing the problem.

```
format.setMajorVersion(3);
format.setMinorVersion(3);
```

After removing them it works fine!